# To put blank space in between selected values from a set of checkbox in lightning

Tags: lightning

We have a set of checkboxes used in lightning design system.Once I select the values in the set. Those are shown as semi-colon seperated values.When I put some empty space in between these values, the blank space shows in salesforce classic but not in lightning. 
Example: 
In classic:

```
IPO ;Registration ;Manufacturing
```

In Lightning:

```
IPO;Registration;Manufacturing
```

I need to put these spaces in between the values in lightning also.
Suggestions will be helpful!!
Thanks.

Comment: It is just the UI issue? How are you populating the field?

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap each value in an element (span of div) and use CSS to add the space. Use the iterator to print out the values. An array of selected values cleaner than a concatenated string.